# What is this building in Bilbao?

Tags: spain, identify-this, architecture, basque-country

I was in Bilbao last week and I saw this building that seemed out of place with its surroundings. It looked abandoned (broken windows, graffiti) but very imposing. And it probably had a great view.

[image: I am attaching a photo to help]

Comment: `r/evilbuildings`. I used to go in that elevator a lot when I was a kid! You would pay it with a bus-pass. Google "ascensor de begoña" for more results  (more than if you would google it in Basque at least)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is an elevator, by which you could reach the Parque Extebarria and the Basilica Begoña. According both to (Basque-only) [Wikipedia article](https://eu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bego%C3%B1ako_igogailua) and [various](http://www.deia.com/2015/10/20/bizkaia/bilbao/el-solar-del-fronton-podria-dar-acceso-al-ascensor-de-begona) [other](http://www.elcorreo.com/bizkaia/201609/16/preven-nuevos-usos-para-20160915234854.html) [sources](https://structurae.net/structures/ascensor-de-begona) it was in use until 2014 and later abandoned. It's still not functioning as of July 2017.

The exact location is shown here: [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/43%C2%B015'37.8%22N+2%C2%B055'19.4%22W/@43.2589797,-2.9216131,260a,35y,39.43t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d43.2605083!4d-2.92205)